# How do I get the requests HttpHeaders in a CDI bean in Quarkus?

Tags: java, http-headers, quarkus, resteasy, context-injection

I would like to get the AcceptableLanguage header of the originating request to select the correct translation language.

I thought that this would work:

```
import javax.ws.rs.core.HttpHeaders;

@ApplicationScoped
public class TranslationService{

   @Context HttpHeaders httpHeaders;
....
}
```

As it seems, I always result in a `null` value. When I try the `@Context` field directly in a RestEasy controller, the field is assigned with the current HttpHeaders object.

I already have tried to save the http headers inside a `ContrainerRequestFilter` to a `@RequestScoped` bean, althought the value seems to get lost again until the use in my `TranslationService`.

How can I, in quarkus, get or provide the requests http headers, so any bean can access them?

Comment: `@Context` injection only works in JAX-RS resources. So that won't ever work. Your attempt to store headers to a `@RequestScoped` bean inside a `ContainerRequestFilter` and injecting that bean should work, though. Maybe add that code so someone can figure out what's wrong with it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It actually did work with a `ContainerRequestFilter`

I added the following filter

```
@Provider
@PreMatching
public class UserInfoProvider implements ContainerRequestFilter {

    private final UserInfo userinfo;

    @Inject
    public UserInfoProvider(UserInfo userinfo) {
        this.userinfo = userinfo;
    }

    @Override
    public void filter(ContainerRequestContext requestContext) {
        List<Locale> acceptableLanguages = requestContext.getAcceptableLanguages();
        userinfo.setAcceptableLanguages(acceptableLanguages);
    }
}
```

of which the bean `UserInfo` is `@RequestScoped`